# Can I have a file in my git repo that git ignores even if that file is added to the repo

Tags: git

I work with a repo that includes a .vscode folder with a settings.json file:

repo
.vscode
settings.json

I like to change this settings.json file but do not want to check my changes in. Also I do not want to consider git my working directory to be changed. I added the file to .git/info/exclude but the file still shows up as modified.

I believe that the exclude file works only for files that are not in the repo.

Is it possible that I "override" a file that is in the repo with my own version, such that it does not show up as modified?

Comment: Yes, with `git update-index --asume-unchanged the-file`. That is a _local_ operation so no other repos are affected by it,

Comment: perfect, great help, thx so much. if you post the command as answer i am happy to mark it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+commit+file+ignore+changes